# can't really understand why setting a margin right for dd description will get the result as it does

Tags: html, css, margin

At the bottom you have the full markup.

If I have margin:0; in the style declaration "#sweden dd" the text will surround the image that is floating left. This is easy to understand but if I change the margin style in "#sweden dd"
so instead of margin:0; I set margin:0 0 0 98p; the text will be lined up beside the image in a column.

So what I can't really get into my head is why will the text be lined up in a column when I have specified margin:0 0 0 98p;
I know that the last number in my margin style is margin-left so that is not the question.

```
//start markup causing text to surround the image that is float left
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body
            {
                font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size:small;
            }

            #sweden
            {
                float:left;
                width:300px;
                padding:10px 0;
                border:2px solid #C8CDD2;
                background:url(img/bg.gif)no-repeat top left;
            }

            #sweden dl /* block element */
            {
                 float:left;
                 margin:10px 20px;
                 padding:0;
            }

            #sweden dt   /* block element */
            {
                 float:right;
                 margin:0;
                 padding:0;
                 font-size:130%;
                 letter-spacing:1px;
                 color:#627081;
                 width:162px;    
                 background:red;
            }

            #sweden dd
            {
                margin:0; /* This will surround the image with text */
               /* margin:0 0 0 98p; This will keep the text beside the image in a column. */
               padding:0;
               font-size:85%;  
               line-height:1.5em;
               color:#666;
               background:yellow;
           }

           #sweden dd.img img
           {
                float:left;
                margin: 0 8px 0 0;
                padding:4px;
                border:1px solid #D9E0E6;
                border-bottom-color:#C8CDD2;
                border-right-color:#C8CDD2;
                background:#fff;
            }

            #sweden dl dd.img
           {
               margin:0;
           }
       </style>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <title>Chapter 3</title>
       </head>
           <body>
           <div id="sweden">
                   <dl>
                       <dt>Stockholm</dt>
                       <dd class="img"><img src="img/gamlastan.jpg" width="80" height="80" 
                           alt="Gamla Stan" /></dd>    
                       <dd>This was taken in Gamla Stan.This was taken in Gamla Stan. 
                           This was taken in Gamla. This was taken in Gamla Stan. 
                           This was taken in Gamla Stan.This was taken in Gamla Stan.
                           This was taken in Gamla. This was taken in Gamla Stan.
                           This was taken in Gamla Stan.This was taken in Gamla Stan.
                           This was taken in Gamla Stan. This was taken in Gamla Stan.
                           This was taken in Gamla Stan.This was taken in Gamla Stan.
                           This was taken in Gamla Stan.This was taken in Gamla Stan.
                           This was taken in Gamla Stan.This was taken in Gamla Stan.
                           This was taken in Gamla Stan.This was taken in Gamla Stan.</dd>
                   </dl>
               </div>
           </body>
       </html>
//Tony
```

Comment: Please save your code in the http://www.jsfiddle.net editor and give us the link so we can run it and see what you mean that is happening.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way css floats work.

> The float CSS property specifies that an element should be taken from
>   the normal flow and placed along the left or right side of its
>   container, where text and inline elements will wrap around it. ([mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float))

On the other hand, when you apply your left margin of 98px -

the text won't wrap around your image anymore because of the margin

Answer (score 0):

In the margin property value, use `98px` instead of `98p`.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/nr4d5/).

Comment: That doesn't really say much. What `p` are you talking about? Please note answers should not be dependent on external resources.

Comment: @JanDvorak Sorry. This better?

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML code you've wrapped the text in the element `<dd>` which you've given a left margin of 98 to.

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/FmLjn/2/

```
<div id="sweden">
                   <dl>
                       <dt>Stockholm</dt>
                       <dd class="img"><img src="img/gamlastan.jpg" width="80" height="80" 
                           alt="Gamla Stan" /></dd> 

                       <dd>
                       This was taken in Gamla Stan.This was taken in Gamla Stan. 
                           This was taken in Gamla. This was taken in Gamla Stan. 
                           This was taken in Gamla Stan.This was taken in Gamla Stan.
                           This was taken in Gamla. This was taken in Gamla Stan.
                           This was taken in Gamla Stan.This was taken in Gamla Stan.
                           This was taken in Gamla Stan. This was taken in Gamla Stan.
                           This was taken in Gamla Stan.This was taken in Gamla Stan.
                           This was taken in Gamla Stan.This was taken in Gamla Stan.
                           This was taken in Gamla Stan.This was taken in Gamla Stan.
                           This was taken in Gamla Stan.This was taken in Gamla Stan.
                       </dd>
                   </dl>
               </div>
```

This means that the whole element is given a margin of 98px from the left hand inner side of the parent container, `<div id='sweden'>`, and displays like a column as a result- this is regardless of whatever is floated (the image). If you want a wider gap between the image and the text, with the text still wrapping around the image, you need to change the padding/margins on the floated element itself and not the wrapped text.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/q9rek/

Answer (score 0):

If you see margin syntax.. it says **`margin:top right bottom left`**..

so here is your updated code for sweden dd
Hope this is what you are looking for.

```
 #sweden dd
                {
                    /*margin:0;  This will surround the image with text */
                    margin:0 0 0 98px; /*This will keep the text beside the image in a column. */
                   padding:0;
                   font-size:85%;  
                   line-height:1.5em;
                   color:#666;
                   background:yellow;


               }
```

and here is the **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xDxC3/2/)**